# Desicion Network Example

Tags: artificial-intelligence

I'am reading this example, but Could you explain a little more, I dont get the part when it says "then we Normalize"... 
I know

```
P(sun) * P(F=bad|sun)  = 0.7*0.2 = 0.14
P(rain)* P(F=bad|rain) = 0.3*0.9 = 0.27
```

But where do they get

```
W    P(W | F=bad)
-----------------
sun     0.34
rain    0.66
```

Example [from](http://inst.eecs.berkeley.edu/~cs188/fa10/slides/FA10%20cs188%20lecture%2018%20--%20decision%20diagrams%20%286PP%29.pdf)

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To normalize a list of numbers, you divide each by the sum of the list.

e.g. python

```
>>> v = [0.14, 0.27]
>>> s = sum(v)
>>> print s
0.41000000000000003
>>> vnorm = [n/s for n in v]
>>> print vnorm
[0.34146341463414637, 0.65853658536585369]
```